# Two norms $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2$ on a vector space $V$ are equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Two norms $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2$ on a vector space $V$ are equivalent iff there exist positive constants $C_1,C_2$ such that $$C_1||.||_1 \leq ||.||_2 \leq C_2||.||_1$$ for all $x \in V$.

I have taken the sequential definition of equivalent metrics i.e. if a sequence $(x_n)$ converge to $x$ in one metric then it implies convergence of $(x_n)$ to $x$ in other metric and conversely.

I  proved that if there exist positive constants $C_1,C_2$ such that $C_1||.||_1 \leq ||.||_2 \leq C_2||.||_1$ for all $x \in V$ then norms $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2$  are equivalent.

But finding difficulty in proving the other part!!

Comment: This question has been answered at least 50 times on this site.

Comment: see:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111253/how-convergence-relates-to-equivalence-of-norms

Comment: please attach some link!!